# Getting Error while installing

Tags: uefi

error: premature end of casper/vmlinuz.efi.
unaligned pointer 0xc7923008
Aborted.Press any key to exit._

Whenever I start installing it gives me this error.I don't know how to remove this error. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you disabled secure boot. Well, I don't see much girls here but Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

Comment: Possibly the installation disc is corrupted. You can check this with the MD5 sum of the disc image, by following these instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

Comment: The file `casper/vmlinuz.efi` is the Linux kernel on the installation medium. A message about the "premature end" of that file strongly suggests either a corrupted download, as Carl H suggests, or a problem creating your installation medium from that file. Was it burned to a DVD or written to a USB flash drive? What tool did you use to create it? Were there any errors reported when you created it? It's also conceivable there was a read error, especially if you burned a DVD on a different computer than the one that's reading it.

Comment: It was burned to USB flash drive and i have used universal USB installer.There were no errors when I created it.Also i have disabled secure boot.

Comment: Check the md5sum of the original image file, as Carl H suggests. If it's OK, verify that your USB flash drive is large enough to hold the entire image. If it is, use another program (or possibly just different options in the program you're using) to create the image. Every program does things in its own ways, and the tool you used might have a quirk that's causing it to fail on your hardware.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and, like Rod says above, the file `casper/vmlinuz.efi` is the Linux kernel on the installation medium. So if you're getting this error, it's a problem with your USB flash drive.

To fix it, I formatted my USB flash drive and copied my Live CD back onto it. That fixed it for me and, if that helps you, please mark this answer as correct. Thank you!